# Exporting CSV response laravel 5.5 and download as csv file

Tags: laravel, export-to-csv

I am trying to export and download some data in a csv file using an ajax request. I was able to output the data in a json response to test but could not get it to download in a data.csv file

### Following is the code I have written so far

```
   public function download(Request $request)
    {

        if(!empty($request->input('my_checkbox')))
        {
             $studentIdToExportArray = $request->input('my_checkbox');
            //$msg = is_array($studentIdToExportArray);//returns true
            $selectedStudents = [];   
            foreach($studentIdToExportArray as $student_id)
            {
                    $student = Students::find($student_id);
                    array_push($selectedStudents, $student);
            }
            header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
            $output=fopen("php://output","w");
            fputcsv($output,array("ID","firstname","surname","email","nationality","address_id","course_id"));

            foreach($selectedStudents as $s1)
            {
                $array = json_decode(json_encode($s1), true);
                fputcsv($output, $array);
            }
            fclose($output);    

            return response()->json([
                   'test'=> $selectedStudents 
            ]);           
        }


    }
```

### Screenshot of output response in console

[image]

Problem: The file data.csv does not download

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try:**

```
$file=fopen('../storage/app/test.csv','w');

$headers = array(
    'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
);

$path = storage_path('test.csv');
return response()->download($path, 'test.csv', $headers);
```

Comment: tried it, but it does not download..Laravel.log "Resource id #249" does not exist "

Comment: @NurulAlam try with my updated answer, please. you need to change the fopen line and also the file path

Comment: the file saves in the storage folder. But it does not download.Could you kindly tell me how do i start the download on a browser?

Comment: @NurulAlam Can you tell me where exactly the file is being stored?

Comment: @NurulAlam Assuming its the storage folder, I've modified my answer.

Comment: apparently ajax call wont initiate a download. Now i have created a link that points to storage (which i have moved to public), Thanks for the help

Comment: @NurulAlam great :) Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

You first have to save the file to a location on your local or a cloud disk and then do a file response or a download response. These are the download options like shown in the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#file-responses

```
return response()->download($pathToFile);

return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);

return response()->download($pathToFile)->deleteFileAfterSend(true)
```

ps: you can also look at using a dedicated package for this, or just use the package as a reference. https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel