# Laravel 5 : Ajax response download not working

Tags: ajax, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

Tried below code:

```
$headers = [
        'Cache-Control'       => 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
        'Content-type'        => 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename=list.csv',
        'Expires'             => '0',
        'Pragma'              => 'public'   
      ];

    $list = List::all()->toArray();

    # add headers for each column in the CSV download
    array_unshift($list, array_keys($list[0]));
    $FH = fopen(storage_path('list.csv'),'w');
    foreach ($list as $row) { 
        fputcsv($FH, $row);
    }
    fclose($FH);

    $path = storage_path('list.csv');

    return response()->download($path, 'list.csv', $headers);
```

Below will out put in inspect element network call

[image]

I have got the same issue in Stack overflow but not working for me.
[Exporting CSV response laravel 5.5 and download as csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48802700/exporting-csv-response-laravel-5-5-and-download-as-csv-file)

Can have any idea regarding this what I have missing in here?

Comment: Why inspect element network call is all blurred ?

Comment: Its fetches all customers secrete data so I blurred it.

Comment: Does list.csv exist in storage_path() ?

Comment: Yes list.csv is exist on storage_path and also data are write on csv.

Comment: Is this a POST request?

Comment: Yes, this is a POST request.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? To prompt the user to download the file? My guess is that this isn't possible in an AJAX request. Try using a normal form (maybe with `target="_blank"`).

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, I exactly want to write data on CSV and download it using AJAX. and I have also checked and tried one another example in the stack overflow. which is I added in question but I can't download it using this same issue's solution. but this issue solves there. yes, the target will be done but it's not a requirement. May anything I miss here. I have no Idea about it.